# Strange behavior of Regular Expression matching numbers in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, numbers

Can anybody find a mistake in the following regex:

regex = ([.0-9]+[/–_\":・’ー‘‐`─'.,-\0-9]*)

My intention is to match "numerical" strings of any kind but if the number is followed by e.g. a letter I just want to get the number.

When I use it with the following sentences:
`s1 = Bla bla 805P bla 1080P; bla bla`
`s2 = Bla bla 5600p bla 5400p`
It finds `805P` and `1080P` in `s1` and `5600` and `5400` in `s2`.
You can check it using http://regexpal.com

I also used this regex in Regex Buddy and it gives me a description that says nothing about letters.
Does anybody have any idea why am I catching `P` and `P;` in `s1` if there is no letters included in the second group of characters?

Comment: What do you mean with `\0` in the second regex group?

Comment: It should be a double backslash, i.e. escaped backslash. I think it displays it as a single backslash for whatever reason. When I edit my post there are two backslashes before 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of your regexp says `[... ,-\\ ...]`, which will include any characters between comma and backslash, which includes the following characters:

```
,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\
```

This, incidentally, includes `P`.

To match a literal minus sign in a character class, it needs to be first, last or escaped. E.g.

```
[- ... ,\\ ... ]
[ ... ,\\ ... -]
[ ... ,\-\\ ... ]
```

would all be valid ways to write what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

You're escaping the `0`, not the `-`, with `-\0`. Also, that is very complex; all you need is

```
pattern = "([.0-9]+[^A-Za-z]*)"
```

I.e. "One or more numbers or periods followed by as many non-letter characters as possible". You can add more characters to ignore to that second block if required. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hA1dG6/2)